# Reactive event in R Shiny Dashboard --> addImageQuery does not respond to event

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard, reactive

I am building a Shiny dashboard to display a series of raster maps. The user can choose which raster map to display from a dropdown menu. One of the requirements is that the user can determine the exact raster value on the map. My solution is to use the `addImageQuery()` function, which queries for the map value on mouse-over.

The `addImageQuery()` function works perfectly when the dashboard is opened initially. My reactive dropdown menu also works as expected, as the map content and the legend change accordingly. HOWEVER, for some reason the `addImageQuery()` function does not change when a new raster is selected. The function still queries the value of the original raster map that is shown when opening the dashboard.

Does anyone know why the `addImageQuery()` function appears not to respond to my reactive event?

**Reproducible example (requires setwd to work):**

```
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(raster)

# Set working directory to where this script is saved
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

# Define dashboard UI 
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Testing addImageQuery function!"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 9,
             leafletOutput("myMap", height = 500)
             ),
      column(width = 3,
             box(selectInput(inputId = "inputRaster",
                             label = "Select raster",
                             choices = c("no2", "c6h6"),
                             selected = "no2")
            )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Function for making the raster map
  makeRasterMap <- function(inputRaster){
    # Define projection
    RD_Proj4 = '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857330322398,0.350732676542563,-1.8703473836068,4.0812 +no_defs'
    
    # Download the .asc file based on the inputRaster
    if (inputRaster == "no2"){
      no2 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/foq2yufvi3694gt/conc_no2_2019.asc?dl=1"   
      download.file(no2, "no2.asc")
      rasterData <- raster("no2.asc", crs = RD_Proj4)
    }
    if (inputRaster == "c6h6"){
      c6h6 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0wu09jsapfmq8s/conc_c6h6_2019.asc?dl=1"
      download.file(c6h6, "c6h6.asc")
      rasterData <- raster("c6h6.asc", crs = RD_Proj4)
    }
    
    # Define color palette
    pal <- colorNumeric(c("#0C2C84", "#41B6C4", "#FFFFCC"), values(rasterData),
                        na.color = "transparent")
    
    # Make leaflet
    map <- leaflet() %>%
      addRasterImage(rasterData, project = TRUE, colors = pal, group = "value") %>%
      addImageQuery(rasterData, project = TRUE, prefix = inputRaster, digits = 2,
                    layerId = "value") %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = values(rasterData),
                opacity = 1.0, position = "bottomright",
                title = inputRaster)
    return(map)
  }
  
  # Make the leaflet map based on the input raster
  observeEvent(input$inputRaster, {
    output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
      map <- makeRasterMap(input$inputRaster)
      map
    })
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem fully reproducible. What is sectInput(inputId = "inputRaster",...)? Do you mean selectInput?

Comment: So sorry, I forgot to make a final change. It should work now

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems to be working... after >20s

Comment: That is a terrible loading time indeed. I adapted the script to save the Dropbox files locally instead of directly importing them as rasters. It's a lot faster now.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/r-spatial/leafem/issues/17? You need to update your `layerId` in the `addImageQuery` call. Then it should work.

Comment: My man! That indeed solved the problem